# jquery ui- Autocomplete selects value instead of label

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

This is my coding

```
$("#txtBox").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '@Url.Action("Get", "Ctrl")',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: "{ 'mode': 'associate','prefix': '" + request.term + "' }",
                        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            var transformed = $.map(data, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.Name,
                                    value: item.Id
                                };
                            });
                            response(transformed);
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            alert('error');
                        },
                    });
                },
                minLength: 3,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    console.log('ui.item.label', ui.item.label);
                    $('#txtBox').val(ui.item.label);
                },
                focus: function (event, ui) {
                    console.log('ui.item.label - focus', ui.item.label);
                    $('#txtBox').val(ui.item.label);
                }
            });
        });
```

I am getting Name and Id from c# controller as Json. I want to the auto complete textbox to display Name and while sending it back to backend while saving, I wanted to send the Id of the Name. But now when I type the name and select the name from the list of suggestions. The Id gets displayed in the text box instead of name.Where am i making the mistake. Can some one guide me on this.

Comment: Based on the Examples, you will want to `return false` for both `select` and `focus`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to keep two `<input />` one type=text and other type=hidden. You can initialize autocomplete on the type=text, and set the value in type=hidden and in server you can access the value of type hidden.

e.g.

```
<input type="text" id="txtBox" name="label" />
<input type="hidden" id="valBox" name="value" />

$("#txtBox").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '@Url.Action("Get", "Ctrl")',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: "{ 'mode': 'associate','prefix': '" + request.term + "' }",
                        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            var transformed = $.map(data, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.Name,
                                    value: item.Id
                                };
                            });
                            response(transformed);
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            alert('error');
                        },
                    });
                },
                minLength: 3,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    console.log('ui.item.label', ui.item.label);
                    $('#txtBox').val(ui.item.label);
                    $('#valBox').val(ui.item.value);
                },
                focus: function (event, ui) {
                    console.log('ui.item.label - focus', ui.item.label);
                    $('#txtBox').val(ui.item.label);
                }
            });
        });
```

In your controller, you can access both values Request["label"], Request["value"]